# CSS: using font face only on mac

Tags: css, font-face, fallback

@font-face is awesome but it displays quiet hideously on PCs. Only on Macs (don't know about linux) does it display naturally. How can I display a special font only for mac users and fallback to a regular font for PC users?

Thanks!

Comment: Guess you are referring to a WinXP PC with ClearType disabled?

Comment: @SalmanPK: They display hideously even with ClearType enabled.

Comment: Hmm what browser are you using?

Comment: @SalmanPK: Firefox 4. IE9 is pretty much the only Windows browser that uses [a new ClearType engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794296/why-font-looks-much-better-in-ie9/5794643#5794643) which actually makes fonts look pretty. That said, on my desktop Firefox mysteriously uses IE9's font rendering engine, but I haven't been able to get it to do the same on any other PC...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind using JavaScript and jQuery, you can detect the OS using the [jQuery client plugin](http://stoimen.com/jquery.client.plugin/) and then set the fonts. It seems to be old stuff but it works with jQuery 1.3.2 and I would not be surprised if it works with jQuery 1.6.1.

```
<script src="./jquery-1.3.2.js"></script> 
<script src="./jquery.client.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    if($.client.os == 'Mac')
        $('body').css('font-family',"'Looks good in Mac'")
    else if($.client.os == 'Windows')
        $('body').css('font-family',"'Looks good in Windows'")
    else if($.client.os == 'Linux')
        $('body').css('font-family',"'Looks good in Linux'")
</script>
```

You can replace `body` with any CSS selector, even if it is not supported by the browser, it is likely supported by jQuery.

[jQuery is available from jquery.com](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#Current_Release)

Full `jquery.client.js`

```
(function() {

    var BrowserDetect = {
        init: function () {
            this.browser = this.searchString(this.dataBrowser) || "An unknown browser";
            this.version = this.searchVersion(navigator.userAgent)
                || this.searchVersion(navigator.appVersion)
                || "an unknown version";
            this.OS = this.searchString(this.dataOS) || "an unknown OS";
        },
        searchString: function (data) {
            for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                var dataString = data[i].string;
                var dataProp = data[i].prop;
                this.versionSearchString = data[i].versionSearch || data[i].identity;
                if (dataString) {
                    if (dataString.indexOf(data[i].subString) != -1)
                        return data[i].identity;
                }
                else if (dataProp)
                    return data[i].identity;
            }
        },
        searchVersion: function (dataString) {
            var index = dataString.indexOf(this.versionSearchString);
            if (index == -1) return;
            return parseFloat(dataString.substring(index+this.versionSearchString.length+1));
        },
        dataBrowser: [
            {
                string: navigator.userAgent,
                subString: "Chrome",
                identity: "Chrome"
            },
            {   string: navigator.userAgent,
                subString: "OmniWeb",
                versionSearch: "OmniWeb/",
                identity: "OmniWeb"
            },
            {
                string: navigator.vendor,
                subString: "Apple",
                identity: "Safari",
                versionSearch: "Version"
            },
            {
                prop: window.opera,
                identity: "Opera"
            },
            {
                string: navigator.vendor,
                subString: "iCab",
                identity: "iCab"
            },
            {
                string: navigator.vendor,
                subString: "KDE",
                identity: "Konqueror"
            },
            {
                string: navigator.userAgent,
                subString: "Firefox",
                identity: "Firefox"
            },
            {
                string: navigator.vendor,
                subString: "Camino",
                identity: "Camino"
            },
            {       // for newer Netscapes (6+)
                string: navigator.userAgent,
                subString: "Netscape",
                identity: "Netscape"
            },
            {
                string: navigator.userAgent,
                subString: "MSIE",
                identity: "Explorer",
                versionSearch: "MSIE"
            },
            {
                string: navigator.userAgent,
                subString: "Gecko",
                identity: "Mozilla",
                versionSearch: "rv"
            },
            {       // for older Netscapes (4-)
                string: navigator.userAgent,
                subString: "Mozilla",
                identity: "Netscape",
                versionSearch: "Mozilla"
            }
        ],
        dataOS : [
            {
                string: navigator.platform,
                subString: "Win",
                identity: "Windows"
            },
            {
                string: navigator.platform,
                subString: "Mac",
                identity: "Mac"
            },
            {
                string: navigator.userAgent,
                subString: "iPhone",
                identity: "iPhone/iPod"
            },
            {
                string: navigator.platform,
                subString: "Linux",
                identity: "Linux"
            }
        ]

    };

    BrowserDetect.init();

    window.$.client = { os : BrowserDetect.OS, browser : BrowserDetect.browser };

})();
```

Comment: hole cow, that's so much better!

Answer (score 3):

The jQuery client plugin is very cool. To do the OS sniffing at least with plain JavaScript (which I'm assuming would save some overhead), you can do:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var os = navigator.platform;
    if (os.indexOf("Mac") != -1) {
        $('body').css( 'font-family', '"Lucida Grande"' );
    }
    else if (os.indexOf("Win") != -1) {
        $('body').css( 'font-family', '"Arial"' );
    }
    else if (os.indexOf("iPhone") != -1) {
        $('body').css( 'font-family', '"Helvetica"' );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As much as I agree with you about Windows, I'm afraid you won't be able to use CSS alone to tell a Mac browser from a Windows browser. You'll need to use a server-side script (or maybe JavaScript?) to sniff that, and decide accordingly whether or not to load `@font-face` CSS.

Comment: This sucks :) How should I go about doing so in PHP?

Comment: There are plenty of questions and articles that cover that, but the basic idea is either to query `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` and try to extract OS info, or to use `get_browser()` (with a `browscap.ini` file). It's spoofable, but most normal users don't spoof OSes anyway ;)

Comment: Thank you. Will mark this as answered when I can. On to the job of making css file a php file! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647969/detect-exact-os-version-from-browser and http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/supercharge-your-css-with-php-under-the-hood/