# Why does my h1 look different in FF compared to Chrome and Safari?

Tags: css, macos, firefox

The `h1`, `h2`, and `h3` of my site (only on local server atm) are much bolder in FF than in Chrome and Safari. The alignment is also slightly off. Why is this happening and how can I offset it?

**Note:** this is not happening for my partner on Ubuntu (I am on a Mac and the difference is significant).

This is effecting the alignment of everything and since I'm using firebug to get everything juuuust right, this is obviously problematic!

I'll copy the inherited CSS for an element that is behaving badly. I'm not sure if it's needed, but I figure it can't hurt:

```
#show_page_info h1 {
    color: #FFF7E7;
    display: block;
    font: bold 23pt Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 17px 5px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    width: 445px;
}
style3.css (line 342)
Inherited fromdiv#show_page_info
#show_page_info {
    text-align: left;
}
style3.css (line 326)
Inherited fromdiv#show_page_item
.show_item, #show_page_item {
    list-style: none outside none;
}
style3.css (line 295)
Inherited frombody
body {
    color: #333333;
    font: 13pt/1.5 Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}
```

The bolder text is one thing, but the alignment is a colossal pain. If I center in FF, it's off in Chrome, if I center in Chrome, it's off in FF etc.

Thank you in advance!!

**Edit:** html (this is just for the case of the above CSS, this happens for all `h1`,`h2`,`h3`...)

```
<div id="show_page_item">
    <div id="show_page_info">
        <h1>{{show.time|date:"l, N jS"}}
        <span id="show_detail_cost">
        {% if show.cost == 0 %}
            Free!
        {% else %}
            ${{ show.cost|floatformat:"-2" }}
        {% endif %}
        </span>
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show us your HTML as well.

Comment: Are you using a browser CSS reset?

Comment: @Gaurav: I am not using a CSS reset as the one I had originally intended to use caused more issues than it solved. We are pretty far along now at this point though I'd be open to a good recommendation!

Comment: http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/
more info here: http://blog.berndtgroup.net/?p=105

Comment: Thank you jao, but my font is not centered in my title element. I'd like it to be.

Comment: what versions of Chrome/FF are you using? I can't see any difference [here](http://jsfiddle.net/thomas4g/B6WBv/2/) in Chrome 14 & FF8

Comment: @Thomas: I still have a difference when I follow your link. The font is wider (bolder?) as well as positioned closer to the top of the "Result" box. Is this some setting of mine in FF that I am unaware of (it's not zoom, but something else)? Is it possible that it has something to do with my OS?

Comment: Using Chrome 13 and FF5, sorry to not address that initial question. Though I should note, my partner is using FF5 as well and has no issues (on Ubuntu).

Comment: @Matt sorry for the holdup. I have a hunch, but no point posting an answer 'till i'm sure. Does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/thomas4g/B6WBv/4/) still look diff. in your browsers?

Comment: @Thomas. No worries, I appreciate the attention and the fact that you aren't just brushing me off. Yes, the link you provided does still look different. I just deleted/reinstalled FF hoping for a tiny miracle, but no dice.

Answer (score 2):

Per the fonts, each browser renders them differently. Try this to have better control over the weights in moz:

```
        @-moz-document url-prefix() {
    * { font-weight: 100; }
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { font-weight: 400; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Prior to Chrome 14.0.833 (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823988/font-smoothing-techniques-text-shadow-rendering-differently-in-chrome-14-0-833)), the text-shadow is rendered more tightly on the text than Firefox. I think this is what accounts for the apparently "more bold" text in Firefox. Commandrea's answer could be pertinent as well. 
As to the alignment issue; I'm not sure - see my comments on your question.

Comment: It's definitely not just a shadow issue, as I can turn the shadow off and see that it's still both wider and aligned differently. Honestly though, the alignment is by far more troubling as it is the difference between a sharp looking site and a sloppy one. The good news is that this seems to be limited to my computer, the bad news it makes firebug un-useable!

Comment: I realize you (or anybody for that matter) might not be able to solve this problem for me. I genuinely appreciate your help though.

Comment: @Matt hop on into a [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2198/room-for-thomas-shields-and-matt) with me, if you don't mind so we can sort this out without clogging the comments.