# How to smooth out rough looking text in Chrome

Tags: css, text, web

I apologize in advance for this question but it is bugging me and I have not found a solution.

When I view my site tagline in IE the text looks very smooth and sharp but when I view it in Chrome the text has rough looking edges on it. Is there a way I can fix this so that the text looks professional and sharp in chrome as well.

www.jobspark.ca is the website and below is my css

```
#banner-tagline {
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 48px;
font-weight: 500;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
z-index: 4;
top: 50%;
font-family: HelveticaNeueW01-55Roma, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
line-height: 40px;
text-shadow: 0 2px 4px #000;
```

Thanks for your time [image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug and it is the expected behavior beacuse of the way **text-shadow** is handled in Google Chrome.

Check the following links to get more information.

http://thomasshields.net/article/3

[Font Smoothing Techniques?  text-shadow rendering differently in Chrome 14.0.833.0 or higher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823988/font-smoothing-techniques-text-shadow-rendering-differently-in-chrome-14-0-833)

Hope this really helps you