# Font looks great on Localhost and Horrible when live

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts

Here is my font on localhost:

[image]

Here is the same font on Chrome (Windows 7) when the site is live:

[image]

I've tried appliying: **-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased** to the #header's font from [This fix](http://tanookilabs.com/your-fonts-look-bad-in-chrome-heres-the-fix/)

I've also tried using **text-shadow:0 0 0 transparent** from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823988/font-smoothing-techniques-text-shadow-rendering-differently-in-chrome-14-0-833)

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

EDIT:

Here is another example of the difference between my local machine:

[image: Looks great on Localhost!]

and how bad it looks on Chrome (windows) below!

[image: Looks Jagged and poor quality!]

Comment: share url, I think its just bold nothing else; try adding font-weight:normal

Comment: The URL is www.getcitylights.com  @Jack. And thanks for the suggestion! It looks alot better! I just think it's a bit weird that I can't achieve the same look on my development localhost chrome (ubuntu 10.04) and a live version of the site, even if it is font-weight:bold ;)

Comment: @Jack also check out the main header in the top div "100% satisfaction guaranteed". That text shadow looks sooo much worse than on my local dev machine. Chrome (windows) is like making it jagged :(

Comment: and increasing font size to 13px gives it readability and clearness, I can not see your local output, and there is less chance if it looks okay in local it should look okay in live too, nothing changes in-between, and in bigger resolution " 100% Satisfaction Guaranteed!
Call Anytime!" runs over the logo :(

Comment: @Jack check out the new comparison from my edit: The first one is from my localhost where the font looks great on the site. The second is the live version where the font has a crooked look to it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49369/discussion-between-tardavis-and-jack)