# Segoe UI font renders differently in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, fonts

Since IE 11 the Segoe UI font is rendered very differently in the browser, while it renders fine anywhere else in the system (including IE when accessing HTML locally via file:// or HTA). Here are some comparisons:

[image]

IE 8/9/10 render it identically to the second item shown ("IE 11 / file:// URL").

As you can see, Chrome is also slightly thinner, but much better in terms of keeping the previous kerning and widths, which is what I value most here.

I'd like to find a way to force Segoe UI to render as it once has. Things I tried:

- Turning off GPU rendering in IE
- Embedding Segoe UI via @font-face
- Various font-weight values

Ideas?

-- Update --

Looks like the explanation is simpler than I thought. My HTML document mode is 8 (for good yet irrelevant reasons), enforced using the X-UA-Compatible meta. IE 9 and 10 properly use the "right" font rendering system for each mode (WPF-style for 9 and above, GDI-style for 8 and below). IE 11, however, forces WPF-style rendering in all document modes in the "Internet Zone". Both "Intranet" and "Local Computer" zones correctly choose the proper font rendering system.

I'd still like to find a way around this, if there is one.

Comment: Notice how the font is much clearer in IE? That's because it's using [ClearType](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/ClearTypeInfo.mspx).

Comment: They're all using ClearType. That's an OS level setting, mostly. Since IE9, Microsoft has improved (as some would put it) the text rendering in the browser so scaling works much better (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh237264%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but that hasn't broken Segoe UI until IE11, so I'm pretty sure it's unrelated.

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol: Every application tested is using some version of ClearType - [IE just happens to use a different version from the rest of the OS that mirrors WPF's for some reason](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794296/why-does-my-font-look-much-better-in-ie9/5794643#5794643).

Comment: @BoltClock Derp. My apologies. Got too carried away on the idea that "font rendering is not a standardised thing".