# Same browser (Firefox), same font, different rendering on different computers

Tags: html, css, firefox, windows-7, font-face

I've got a problem. I am using titillium weblight font (with standard font-face appliance - including text-rendering: optimizeLegibility, font-weight, line-height etc.). The problem is that the font renders differently on Firefox (same version 31.0) on two different computers, with similar hardware, same resolution, same OS (Windows 7).

On the first computer it renders normally:

[image]

While on the second one it lacks antialiasing as far as I can tell:

[image]

Maybe the difference is not that big that anyone should concern, but it is important for me that every detail of this project will be just fine.

Anyone has any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've run into this myself, I believe it has something to do with certain plugins (not extensions, mind you), because in my case I get a different anti-aliasing effect if I create a new Firefox profile. It affects all text, however, not just those set in specific web fonts.

Comment: Do they have ClearType configured differently?

Comment: Does removing text-rendering: optimizeLegibility helps?

Comment: @minitech: I don't think it's a system ClearType setting. Windows 7's GDI ClearType never renders fonts so smoothly. The smooth rendering resembles that of [WPF and recent versions of IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794296/why-does-my-font-look-much-better-in-ie9/5794643#5794643).

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal: “with standard font-face appliance - including text-rendering: optimizeLegibility”

Comment: @BoltClock: So DirectWrite, then? It still *might* respect the system’s ClearType preferences… I really don’t know, though.

Comment: @minitech: Your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: No, in fact, adding/removing text-rendering: optimizeLegibility doesen't change anything, it was just for the info, that i tried. ;) Anyways - it has nothing to do with system ClearType setting, we've tried that as well.

Answer (score 0):

These three properties together have always worked for me across different browsers.

```
html {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
```

The issue is called "antialiasing" or "subpixel rendering" and it has to do with how the browser/computer treats the edges of your text.  If you're curious you can read more about it [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering).